# Post type category link in menu

Tags: menu, hyperlink, custom-type

how can I include menu link in navigation to custom type category in Wordpress?

I have custom type "movie", and I have about 30 movies, so this is one category. I would like to make a link in navigation so when the user click on movies it will show all movies?

For now I can only see post types in menu. For example; Movie 1, Movie 2, Movie 3....

`show_in_nav_menus` is set to `TRUE`

Here are some images how did I want to make this.
Second image is custom type categories and from where I can click and pick post type category which will be placed into menu.

Thanks in advance!

[image]
[image]

Comment: why dont you just add the movie archive page link to the menu as a custom link?

Comment: Hi thanks for you comment. I know that option, but that option is the last thing on my list. Really want to make simple, as there category for posts I need category for custom, but not to write down the links manual. Anyway, thanks. I did update my question, did add some images.

Comment: did you check in the Screen Options dropdown in the top right to see if your custom post type is there?

Comment: I did, and checked all, but there are no results. I did find some script that will "manipulate" with core of Wordpress and make this happen but really don't want this. I really can not believe that is not possible with few lines or lines that are not relate with core.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, found it!!
If you need to add category for custom post types, you need to add custom taxonomies.

Very usefull tutorial can be found here:
http://wp.smashingmagazine.com/2012/11/08/complete-guide-custom-post-types/